# How do I do this double integral (change of variable)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$B$ is the region bounded by $xy = 1$, $xy = 3$, $x^2 - y^2 = 1$, $x^2 - y^2 = 4$

Find $$\iint\limits_{B}x^2 + y^2 \,dx\,dy$$ using the change of variables:
$$u = x^2 - y^2$$
$$v = xy$$

So I think the limits of integration will now be $v = 1$ to $v = 3$ and $u = 1$ to $u = 4$, but I'm not sure how to put $x^2+y^2$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome! Before anyone else chastises you about the formatting of the post, I figured I'll just give you these links. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

The first one is a good guide for asking high quality questions. This assures you quick answers and helps you find other similar questions which might have been asked.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

This is a quick how-to to use LATEX, the means of typing mathematics on this site. Good luck!

Comment: Note that $(x^2+y^2)^2=(x^2-y^2)^2+4(xy)^2$

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992564/double-integration-with-change-of-variables) might help.