# How to create own transformation change of variables

Tags: calculus, transformation

> Evaluate the following integral using change of variables. Draw the original and new regions
>   of integration.
>
> $$\int\int_{R} \frac{1}{x^2-y^2} dA$$
>
> where R is bounded by the lines
>
> $x + y = 1 ,x + y = e, x − y = 1, x − y = e$

I am used to seeing problems where the desired transformation is given, but I don't understand how to make my own region. Are the new regions simply the partial derivatives of the region given?

Comment: The domain $R$ is a tilted rectangle.  Can you create functions that will map it to a regular rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

"partial derivatives of the region given" doesn't make sense.

But what does make sense is to use the form of $x$ and $y$ given for the region. That is, try $u = x + y$ and $v =x - y$. Then the region in the new coordinates is just $1 \rightarrow e$ for both.

Note also that $uv = x^2 - y^2$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: To the OP: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992564/double-integration-with-change-of-variables) might help. The change of variables proposed by Simon is actually correct. Sometimes you'll find that the Jacobian will cancel out everything as in my example.