# Iterated Integral with variable substitution

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the double integral of the function $f(x,y) = (x+y)^9(x-y)^9$:

$\int_0^{1/2} \int_x^{1-x}  (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 dydx$

I have a solution but I definitely arrived at it after a sloppy attempt. I got `-0.0025`. To begin with, I know you need to separate the variables. I tried integration by parts, but got lost in it. How can I separate the variables to continue the integration?

Comment: I would suggest substituting $u = x+y$, $v = x-y$ if you know how to do substitutions with multiple variables.

Comment: how would I change the corresponding bounds?

Comment: The bounds of the integral when dealing with $x, y$ are $x = 0$, $y = 1-x$, and $y = x$. Rewrite these bounds so that they contain only $u, v$.

Comment: how would I use that with $du = dx + dy$ and $dv = dx - dy$?

Comment: you need to calculate the jacobian to substitute out $dydx$, like in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992564/double-integration-with-change-of-variables?rq=1

Comment: @Hwai-Ray Tung, using the Jacobian.

Comment: so I get $dudv = 2xydxdy$. How do I proceed from there to get the bounds?

Comment: maybe your current level of formal mathematical education isn't sufficent to tackle such integrals. it might be better to first accquire some knowledge about multidimensional integrals before proceeding further!

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to solve this integral with substitution. Since we want to separate the variables in the Integral
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{1/2} \int_x^{1-x}  (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 dy\,dx\tag{1}
\end{align*}

it's reasonable to use  the substitution

\begin{align*}
\left.
\begin{matrix}
u=x+y\\
v=x-y\\
\end{matrix}
\right\}
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
x=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)\\
y=\frac{1}{2}(u-v)
\end{matrix}
\right.\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> According to the *[Change of variable theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html)* we want to calculate
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_{1}}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx
> =\int_{u_0}^{u_1}\int_{v_0}^{v_{1}}f(x(u,v),y(u,v))
> \left|\operatorname{det}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x_u&x_v\\
> y_u&y_v
> \end{pmatrix}
> \right|
> \,dv\,du\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Jacobian**
>
> At first we calculate the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix
>   \begin{align*}
> \left|\operatorname{det}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x_u&x_v\\
> y_u&y_v
> \end{pmatrix}
> \right|=
> \left|\operatorname{det}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
> \frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{2}
> \end{pmatrix}
> \right|
> =\frac{1}{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Area transformation**
>
> We observe from (1) the region of integration is 
>   \begin{align*}
> &0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
> &x\leq y\leq 1-x
> \end{align*}
>
> This is the area of a triangle with three lines as boundary lines,  the $y$-axis  $x=0$, the  major diagonal $x=y$ and a parallel to the minor diagonal through $(1,0)$, $y=1-x$.
>
> Since the transformation (2) is linear, lines are transformed to lines. So, the transformed $(u,v)$-area is again enclosed by three lines.
>
> \begin{array}{lclcl}
> x=0\qquad&\rightarrow&\qquad \frac{1}{2}(u+v)=0
> &\qquad\rightarrow&u=-v\\
> x=y\qquad&\rightarrow&\qquad \frac{1}{2}(u+v)=\frac{1}{2}(u-v)
> &\qquad\rightarrow&v=0\\
> y=1-x\qquad&\rightarrow&\qquad \frac{1}{2}(u-v)=1-\frac{1}{2}(u+v)
> &\qquad\rightarrow&u=1\\
> \end{array}
>
> We see the $(u,v)$-triangle area is given by the three lines $u=-v, v=0$ and $u=1$ which can be written as
>   \begin{align*}
> 0\leq u \leq 1\\
> -u\leq v\leq 0
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Integration**
>
> Now we have all ingredients to perform the integration according to (3). We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_x^{1-x}  (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 dy\,dx
> &=\int_0^1\int_{-u}^0(uv)^9\cdot\frac{1}{2}\,dv\,du\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1u^9\left(\int_{-u}^0v^9\,dv\right)\,du\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1u^9\left(\left.\frac{1}{10}v^{10}\right|_{-u}^0\right)\,du\\
> &=-\frac{1}{20}\int_0^1u^{19}\,du\\
> &=-\frac{1}{20}\left.\left(\frac{1}{20}u^{20}\right)\right|_{0}^1\\
> &=-\frac{1}{400}
> \end{align*}